# Place tiles in circular fashion

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, geometry, tile

I need to place tiles in this fashion:

[image]

I only need the logic, so language doesn't matter.Thank you!

The number of tiles is unknown!

This is how far I got:

```
var setX = 0;
var setY = 0;
var count = 0;
$(".pic").each(function() 
{ 
   // set setX and setX based on count 
   $(this).animate({"left":setX,"top":setY},2000) 
   count++
});
```

Comment: Where did you get stuck while trying to implement it?

Comment: What would be the position of `1`; the coordinate pair `(0,0)` or some predifined position? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What kind of space are you expecting between each item?

Comment: a tile is 50 pixels wide and 50 pixel heigh

Comment: Shouldn't you be altering the values of `setX` and `setY`?  (And shouldn't you *not* be calling variables by names better suited for functions?)

Comment: true, i should call them something else, currentX or currentY. w/e And yes i need to alter their values, but i need the logic for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some implementation in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;                  

public class Program
{

    public struct Pair
    {
        int X;
        int Y;
        public Pair( int X, int Y )
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format( "({0},{1})", X, Y );
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Pair> Positions( int StartX, int StartY )
    {
        int[] DeltaX = { 0, 1, 0,-1 };
        int[] DeltaY = { 1, 0,-1, 0 };

        int Direction = 1;

        int X = StartX;
        int Y = StartY;

        int Left = StartX;
        int Right = StartX;
        int Top = StartY;
        int Bottom = StartY;

        yield return new Pair(X, Y);

        while ( true )
        {
            switch ( Direction )
            {
            case 0:
                Top += 1;
                while ( Y < Top )
                {
                    X += DeltaX[Direction];
                    Y += DeltaY[Direction];
                    yield return new Pair( X, Y );
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                Right += 1;
                while ( X < Right )
                {
                    X += DeltaX[Direction];
                    Y += DeltaY[Direction];
                    yield return new Pair( X, Y );
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                Bottom -= 1;
                while ( Y > Bottom )
                {
                    X += DeltaX[Direction];
                    Y += DeltaY[Direction];
                    yield return new Pair( X, Y );
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                Left -= 1;
                while ( X > Left )
                {
                    X += DeltaX[Direction];
                    Y += DeltaY[Direction];
                    yield return new Pair( X, Y );
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            Direction++;
            Direction %= 4;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var Coords = Positions( 10, 10 ).Take( 15 );
        foreach ( Pair iPair in Coords )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( iPair.ToString() );
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: For those who need this in C# its very helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

You can walk in a spiral from your starting point like a turtle in the 80's turtle graphics: Walk a certain distance straight, then turn right, walk a bit, turn right and so on. Every now and then you have to adjust your walking distance.

You can walk in four different directions. Start facing right and with a step length of one unit. Place a tile after every unit you walk. If you have reached the destination for this step, turn right. When you are facing left or right, increase the step length by one unit.

```
    var x = 350;
    var y = 350;
    var delta = 50;        // tile edge length

    var dir = 0;           // 0 to 3, clockwise: n, e, s, w
    var step = 0;          // current unit edge length of spiral
    var togo = 0;          // how long to go on this edge?
    var n = 49;

    var offset = [      // direction vectors for facing ...
        [0, -1],        // ... north
        [1, 0],         // ... east
        [0, 1],         // ... south
        [-1, 0]         // ... west
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        place_tile(i + 1, x, y);

        if (togo == 0) {
            dir = (dir + 1) % 4;
            if (dir == 1 || dir == 3) step++;
            togo = step;
        }

        togo--;

        x += delta * offset[dir][0]; 
        y += delta * offset[dir][1];
    }
```

The limit of 49 is a bit arbitrary; it will of yourse yield a 7x7 square. Maybe it is better to `break` out of the loop and stop tiling when the step has reached a certain value or when you step off your canvas.

Comment: I almost had it solved but this is better :D Thank you!

Comment: Nice structural implementation!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps for a start:

Assuming you don't know anything about the position of existing tiles:

The "circlesize" grows constantly, starting with 2x2, then 4x4, then 6x6 tiles, let us call this NxN. For each one of the circles you must go once in every direction, starting UP (therefore ZERO would be underneath 1), then right, down, left. You must take N-1 steps in every direction before switching to the next. After completing the circle you must once change an UP for a LEFT to begin the new circle (meaning that ZERO would in fact be where the 2 is).